# Differential Amplifier with active load

Tags: mosfet

I came across this example in Razavi's Analogue CMOS IC Design book

[image]

**The solution says that the for differential output, Vn does not change. Why not?** Is it because any voltage drop across any of the resistors is essentially accounted for at either X or Y?

Comment: I don't see \$V_N\$ in your figure

Comment: Its the 'N' node between the gates of M3 and M4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you apply some differential signal \$V_{in}\$.

Due to the differential gain of the amplifier, \$V_X\$ may now be,

$$ V_X = V_N + \Delta $$

Similarly,

$$ V_Y = V_N - \Delta $$

Since \$R_1\$ = \$ R_2 \$, the voltage diver formed between \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$ yields \$V_n\$.

Due to the symmetry of the differential amplifier, \$V_N\$ appears as an AC ground.

Answer (score 0):

Vn is part of a current source stage, if Vx and Vy are constant, then the current through M3 and M4 will be constant and Vn will not change. This is an assumption of the question.

Comment: I understand that but how can you assume that Vx and Vy will be constant? I mean surely, if Vin1 goes up (which is Vgs for M1), then Id1 should increase too and thus the voltage drop across the load part on the LHS will increase and so voltage at X (Vx) should drop.